# How to create a reference variable in excel

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

Okay I might've not explained it all that well in the title but bear with me.

I have an excel sheet with multiple list dropdowns. These dropdowns are filled with information that I use to generate a URL. The data in the dropdowns change the route parameters of said URL.

This generator is to be used by a marketing team. People who aren't familiar with the complicated codes that are passed as route parameters. I want to make the generator more user friendly.

I want the dropdowns to have understandable values. Such as for the language dropdown to say:

- English
- German
- French

But when select I want these items to have a different value. Like so:

- English = en-GB
- German = de-DE
- French = fr-FR

Is there a function to convert cell data to say something different? Or create an excel variable?

Comment: How about a VLookup on a reference table? Easily maintainable and expandable without the need for macros.

Comment: I think Robin's answer is the simplest and most scalable solution.  If you really want to do VBA, consider the Dictionary class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robin's comment points the way. No need for VBA coding - you can use `Tables`, `Data-Validation` & `VLOOKUP` formula here.

1. Insert a Table over your languages and their corresponding codes (Insert --> Table).
2. I've named my Table `TblLang`, instead of the default "Table1" (overtype the name directly in the top-left text box on the Ribbon when on the Table Tools>Design tab)
3. Add a `Data Validation`, list-type to your user-selected cells. This is my col H, whereby the user can only pick a drop-down value that's in the Language table values. (Found under Data-->Data Validation...)
4. My forumla for the URL is: `="\\http:\myurlpath\ %lang=" & VLOOKUP(H4,TblLang,2,FALSE)`

The formula look's up the value the user has picked from the drop-down cell in the table and returns the exact matched value from column 2, the code.

[image]